# Assigning the result of fopen inside an if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, variable-assignment

I am learning C currently and wanted to know whether the following two pieces of code perform differently, or if it's just a style thing.

Looking at some sources they the have the following code:

```
...
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","r");
if (pFile == NULL)
{ some code }
...
```

While my professor has the following code in his notes:

```
...
FILE * pFile
if ((pFile = fopen("myfile.txt","r")) == NULL)
{ some code }
...
```

Just wanted to know if this is merely a style preference by different programmers or if there is an advantage to putting the return/set line inside the if statmeent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no difference.** More experienced programmers sometimes go with the second form, just to save a line, but they are *essentially identical*.  The second tends to be a little more "UNIX-y", where most function calls are checked for error (as opposed to success) before continuing.

Comment: The second style has advantages for situations like `if (condition && (pFile = fopen("foo","r")) != NULL)`. Might be worth mentioning.

Comment: @DanielFischer, yes. It should be pointed out that that line is using short-circuit evaluation, and the file will only be opened if `condition` is true.

Answer (score 1):

They're identical, since `(pFile = fopen("myfile.txt", "r"))` returns `pFile`, but I would personally prefer the first since it's more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

These two variants are equal. It doesn't affect performance. However, I think the first variant is better because it makes things more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Both programs are equivalent.

Some people favor the first style saying it is more readable and some people favor the second style saying it is more compact.

For information, note that in some coding guidelines ([MISRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) being one) the second style is forbidden. MISRA forbids the use of the assignment operator in the controlling expression of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in performance, but the second is clearly preferable.

The first separates attempting to open the file from testing for success in opening the file.

The second makes opening the file and testing for success a *single* operation, which is exactly how you should not only code it, but also how you should think about it. You shouldn't think of them as two separate operations at all. The operation of opening a file is not complete until/unless you've checked whether it opened correctly or not.

Treating opening and testing as two separate operations is lazy coding that leads to sloppy thinking. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

As said here the two segments are clearly identical. I would however prefer the first as it tends to avoid the confusion between the assignment operator = and the equality operator ==. Consider a situation in which there's a function **foo(arg)** returning an int. You would write something like:

```
int y;

if ((y = foo(x)) == 0) {
    ... some code ...
}
```

Now, let's say you confuse the assignment operator with equality (very common in if expressions BTW):

```
int y;

if ((y == foo(x)) == 0) {
    ... some code ...
}
```

Since the type of the expression **(y == foo(x))** is int, the above is considered a legitimate C code by the compiler. This would clearly produce a bug in your code.

Now, lets consider the first option:

```
int y;

y = foo(x);
if (y == 0) {
    ... some code ...
}
```

Clearly, now you are less likely to confuse the assignment with the equality. Furthermore, even if you do write **y == foo(x);** as a statement the compiler will issue a warning.

Answer (score 0):

While the existing answers are very good, I've got a couple things to add about how to approach the question of whether something in C is a performance issue.

First, a quick way to check is to compile both versions of the code with `gcc -O3` and compare the generated `.o` files. If they're identical, then of course there cannot be any performance difference (at least not with the current compiler/version you're using).

With that said, a more conceptual approach to the question is to ask yourself 2 questions:

1. Do the two pieces of code define exactly the same behavior for all possible valid input variable values, or only the same behavior (or even just similar behavior) for the inputs you expect?
2. If they define exactly the same behavior, do you think it's easy for a compiler to see this?

If so, there "shouldn't" be a performance difference, because the compiler "should" compile them both to whatever it thinks is the most efficient way to achieve the behavior described. Of course sometimes compilers can be pretty stupid, so if it really matters, you may want to check.

In your case, both versions of the code define the exact same behavior, and I think you'd have a hard time finding a compiler that compiled them differently, except perhaps with optimization completely disabled.